# Create gdb file from Sql-Server Views using ArcObject in .Net

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, sql-server, .net

I am able to Create blank .gdb file using arcObjects in .net.

e.g for Create blank gdb file i have wrriten this code.

```
    public IWorkspace CreateFileGdbWorkspace()
    {
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
        IWorkspaceName workspaceName = workspaceFactory.Create("C:\\SampleGDB\\",
          "FileSample.gdb", null, 0);

        IName name = (IName)workspaceName;
        IWorkspace workspace = (IWorkspace)name.Open();
        return workspace;
    }
```

with above code i am able to create FileSample.gdb file. now how can i create gdb using sqlserver database using arcObjects. and fill with data toi gdb file.

Comment: This would be a short Python script.  Using ArcObjects for this purpose is like using a 737 for mail delivery in the bush.  The irony is, once you know the Python steps, the ArcObjects equivalent is only 20-30 lines of simple code for each line of Python.

Comment: Note that File Geodatabase is not a "file" -- it's a *directory* with a number of files in it.  Adding feature classes increases the file count by a wide range of possible values, depending on how many columns and how many indexes are present.

Comment: Thank you, Vince for reply. So is it not possible in .Net?

Comment: It's possible, as the Answer below demonstrates.  It's just not particularly tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Geoprocessor to execute the "CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase" tool.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000162000000

```
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
try
{   
     parameters.Add(@"SQL_SERVER");
     parameters.Add(@"hostname\instancename");
     parameters.Add(@"databasename");
     parameters.Add(@"DATABASE_AUTH");
     parameters.Add(@"username");
     parameters.Add(@"password");
     parameters.Add(@"SDE_SCHEMA");
     parameters.Add(@"sde");
     parameters.Add(@"sde");
     parameters.Add(@"");
     parameters.Add(@"pathtoLicenseFile");

    // Execute the tool.
    object result=gp.Execute("CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase", parameters, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
object src = 1;
Console.WriteLine("Messages: " + gp.GetMessages(ref src));
src = 2;
Console.WriteLine("Warnings: " + gp.GetMessages(ref src));
src = 3;
Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + gp.GetMessages(ref src));
```

Comment: I Have tried this but i am getting error like "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: I edited my answer. Added code to get the plain text error messages.

Comment: Hey steloe.
Thank you for your reply Can please tell me it is used in .Net. because I am not able to create any gdb file. so i think I will doing it wrong way can you please give description about how to use this method. because I am new to arcObject.

Comment: Create a GDB File? I dont understand. What exactly do you want to do? With my code, you can create a SDE Database in MS-SQL-Server.

Comment: No i want to create .gdb file from my MS-Sql-server Database. in .net using arcObjets. I have some views created in Sql-Server from that i just want to create .gdb file.

Comment: So, your question is simply how to copy the featurclasses from the SDE to the FileGDB? Use the geoprocessing tool "copy": http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Copy/001700000051000000/

Comment: yes but i want to do programmatically using arcGis SDK. is it possible?

Comment: You can use the "copy" tool just like tool in my first answer. Just change the parameters according to the documentation and of course the name in the .Execute(..) line.